# C# InvalidCastException Only for One Value?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I have some code to see whether or not some dropdowns have been changed.

```
        private void tbl_TransactionsDataGridView_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox combo = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (combo != null && tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid  
            // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -=
                new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);

            // Add the event handler. 
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged +=
                new EventHandler(ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }

        if (combo != null && tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6)
        {
            // Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid  
            // adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged -=
                new EventHandler(Status_SelectedIndexChanged);

            // Add the event handler. 
            combo.SelectedIndexChanged +=
                new EventHandler(Status_SelectedIndexChanged);
        }
    }
```

When the ColumnIndex is 6, it jumps to the following code. Whats maddening is that this works for any value I select from the dropdown except 1. If I select 1, I get an InvalidCastException, telling me that I need to use a number smaller than infinity. If I select any other number, everything fires as it is supposed to. What am I doing wrong?

```
        private void Status_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object oStatus = new object();
        oStatus = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedValue;

        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(oStatus))
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            if (Convert.ToInt32(oStatus) != 1)
            {
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckInEmployee"].Value = Environment.UserName;
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CloseDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
            }

            if (Convert.ToInt32(oStatus) == 1)
            {
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckOutEmployee"].Value = Environment.UserName;
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckInEmployee"].Value = null;
                tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CloseDate"].Value = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: `if (Convert.ToInt32(oStatus) != 1)`

From my original code and

`if (((int)oStatus) != 1)`

From the suggested solution below.

Comment: what is the type of the object in oStatus?  What is the exact text of the exception message?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to be using `ComboBox.SelectedValue`? That involves data binding and I can't tell what you're binding to.

If you're just adding `int`s to the `ComboBox.Items` collection then use `SelectedItem`. Also this property can return `null`... note that for a `null` input `Convert.IsDBNull` returns `false`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.isdbnull.aspx).

Finally, cast or `Convert` it to an `Int32` like so:

```
private void Status_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object oStatus = new object();
    oStatus = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem;

    if (oStatus != null && !Convert.IsDBNull(oStatus))
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        if (((int)oStatus) != 1)
        {
            tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckInEmployee"].Value = Environment.UserName;
            tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CloseDate"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckOutEmployee"].Value = Environment.UserName;
            tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CheckInEmployee"].Value = null;
            tbl_TransactionsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["CloseDate"].Value = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Or for that matter, you could use `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` instead.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and am getting the same error. The following line is throwing the exception.

`                if (((int)oStatus) != 1)`

Comment: Can you show us the code where you populate the `ComboBox`? Also, can you set a breakpoint at `if (((int)oStatus) != 1)`, and see the type of `oStatus`?